# What's an E class?

Tags: dnd-4e, class, terminology

I'm familiar with the 4e guide terminology for A and V classes: A classes have one primary stat and two secondaries you can choose between, with the choice determining the way the class plays; V classes have a choice of two primary stats to determine how the class plays, but the secondary stat remains the same.

But I've run across a few references to E classes (in various rescues of class handbooks and the comments associated with them, like [this one](http://www.dyasdesigns.com/dragon_phoenix/What%20Is%20Yours%20Can%20Be%20Mine%20%20A%20Thief%27s%20Handbook%20_%20The%20Wizards%20Community.htm) or [this one](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?471429-Tainted-Faith-The-Blackguard-s-Guide)), the meaning of which I can't quite infer from context.

In 4e guide vocabulary, what is an "E class"?

Comment: I've added some references on request. I hope this doesn't lead to speculative answers by people who are unfamiliar with the context beyond the links I provide, as those answers are almost invariably quite poor in quality; this is why I usually do not provide context which expert answerers should already be familiar with. Please prove me wrong this time.

Comment: @BESW I was going to see if I could find similar sources for the E class term itself, but these seem to be colloquial terms, so I doubt they will come up without deep forum searching

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### E is for Essentials

V classes and A classes both follow the standard AEDU (at-will/encounter/daily/utility) power format; the A & V portion describes their use of primary/secondary attributes within that framework. Essentials classes, on the other hand, largely abandon the AEDU format (with the exception of the pure casters) and instead get a variety of special abilities in place of powers.